# TrimStart() spaces in textbox dynamically, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I'd appreciate any advice.

Let's say I have a simple `@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.SomeTextField)`.

When user types some text into it and leaves the textBox (`focusOut()`) I need to shift the text to the left, so that it removes all spaces in the start.

I know I could handle focusOut event and remove spaces, but is there a better way, for example set some property to a textBox?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is such functionality in asp.net, you have to do it by yourself. You may consider JQuery InputMask plugin.

Comment: @JesseJames, I wouldn't like to make a mask or concrete format for a tb, I just need to shift things left.

Comment: There are only html and javascript on client-side. Html doesn't have any trimming functionality. So you have to do it in js. MVC also doesn't have any helpers to generate trimming js.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via jquery like this

```
$.trim($("#textbox").val());
```

and you can do this on `onblur` event of textbox

OR

you can use Trim of C# when this value will be passed to controller

```
 value.Trim()
```

Comment: yeah I knew that, but was looking for a better solution, anyway, thank you

Comment: You can have a javascript function:

function RemoveSpaces(string) {  
  
   return string.split(' ').join('');  
  
   }  
Then set the onblur property of textbox like this: 
onblur="this.value=RemoveSpaces(this.value);"